# CUDA - how to report problem/error from within kernels?

Tags: error-handling, cuda

Let's say I have a kernel that is processing some data and can detect problems with it (overflow, not correct data, etc.). How to set a single flag from multiple threads?

Here is a code sketch for the kernel:

```cpp
__global__ void kernel(float *data) {
    // Processing data here and setting problem=true if something went wrong
    ...
    if (problem) {
        // Do something here
    }
    ...
}
```

and running this kernel:

```cpp
bool isProblemDetected = false;

// Run N-threads of kerenel
kernel<<<1,N>>>(inputData);

// If any of the threads failed to process data I would like to have isProblemDetected set to true here
```

Is the only solution returning from each threads a value and post-checking it after all threads are run, or maybe there is a much simpler and elegant solution?

Comment: What do you mean by `// Run multiple kerenels` -- your example only runs a single kernel with one block. There are no "multiple kernels" in that code example

Comment: My bad - of course I meant to run this one specific kernel with N threads (or in general how to handle error checking with multi-block multi-thread invocation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is just setting up some global variable like:

```
__device__ int isProblemDetected;
```

Then you can set it to 0 before the kernel with:

```
int zero = 0;
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(isProblemDetected, &zero, sizeof(int));
```

And retrieve the value when you are back from the kernel:

```
int wasProblem;
cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&wasProblem, isProblemDetected, sizeof(int));
```

Inside the kernel, you can either just set the variable to 1 when a problem arrises or even use `atomicAdd` to have some kind of problem counter.

I guess there is better ways, but this is the simplest I know.

Comment: ignoring trivialities like whether the variable is statically or dynamically allocated, and precisely how you set `isProblemDetected` from device code, and ignoring methods that corrupt the CUDA context (which nobody wants, generally) there really isn't any other better way.  Any sensible communication from device to host must take place via global memory.